# Siri-like scroll UITableView to bottom/footer

Tags: ios, uitableview, siri

I have the need of scrolling a UITableView to a space which has no current UITableViewCells leaving only the last cell (with variable length) at the top, just like Siri does.

Currently I'm scrolling the UITableView with

```
[mainTableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, mainTableView.frame.size.height-80) animated:YES];
```

however when I "reloadData" on the UITableView the scrolling jumps and I don't get the desired effect of smooth scrolling, just like Siri does.

Is there any easy way to achieve this scrolling need?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution to that is adding a UIView as the UITableView footerView. If your table is let's say 300px tall, and your cells are 44px tall (default for cells) then you will want to add a footerView that is 256px (300-44) height. That way you can scroll to to a position where your last cell will be the only visible and will stay at top (your task to calculate where that position is ;) )

Comment: How we can prevent scroll of tableview to last two cell like siri app. Any suggestion.